# Can't figure out why match result is nil

Tags: ruby, regex

```
>> "<img src=\"https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&amp;height=90&amp;email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&amp;version=4&amp;build=7\" style="">".match(Regexp.new("<a href=\"http(s?):\/\/(?:\w+\.)+\w{1,5}.+?\">|<img src=\"http(s?):\/\/(?:\w+\.)+\w{1,5}.+?\"(?: style=\".+\")?>"))
=> nil
```

But testing in Rubular says it should be catched

[link](http://rubular.com/r/Rzh038onlA)

I can't understand why testing with Rubular says that this string should be catched, and actually it is not.

Comment: It's 2013. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2630790

Comment: All I can say is: Yuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for handling HTML (or XML) 99.9% of the time. Instead, use a parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<img src="https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&amp;height=90&amp;email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&amp;version=4&amp;build=7" style="">'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

url = doc.at('img')['src'] # => "https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&height=90&email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&version=4&build=7"
doc.at('img')['style'] # => ""
```

Once you've retrieved the data you want, such as the `src`, use another "right" tool, such as [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'uri'

scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = URI.split(url)
scheme    # => "https"
userinfo  # => nil
host      # => "filin.mail.ru"
port      # => nil
registry  # => nil
path      # => "/pic"
opaque    # => nil
query     # => "width=90&height=90&email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&version=4&build=7"
fragment  # => nil

query_parts = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(query)]
query_parts # => {"width"=>"90", "height"=>"90", "email"=>"multicc@multicc.mail.ru", "version"=>"4", "build"=>"7"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when you call match on the Regex, although I strongly recommend you don't use a regex to parse HTML.

```
str = '<img src="https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&amp;height=90&amp;email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&amp;version=4&amp;build=7" style="">'

matchData = /<img src="http(?:s?):\/\/(?:\w+\.)+\w{1,5}.+?"(?: style=".+")?>/.match(str)

p matchData[0] # => "<img src=\"https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&amp;height=90&amp;email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&amp;version=4&amp;build=7\" style=\"\">"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
'<img src="https://filin.mail.ru/pic?width=90&amp;height=90&amp;email=multicc%40multicc.mail.ru&amp;version=4&amp;build=7" style="">'.match(/<img src="https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)+\w{1,5}.+?"(?: style=".+")?>/)
```

Not sure why yours doesn't work exactly, although I do notice you forgot to escape the last two double quotes in the match string. I used single quotes to avoid that issue